# laravel php artisan migrate error occured db not creted?

Tags: laravel-5.5

[image]

when i run php artisan migrate command for creating db table in database then i got this error please tell me. that how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite clear. The table already exists. To resolve that, login to your database and drop the table.

```
DROP TABLE users;
```